# Hypergeometric expansion approximation

Tags: hypergeometric-function

We've [identified](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7961) a bug in our hypergeometric function, where the approximation that we're using fails.

Basically, we approximate `hyp2f1(a, b, c, x)` where `b==c` and `|x| < 1.0` as `(1.0 - x)^(-a)`. However, this approximation seems to fail when `b` is a negative integer such that `|b| < 100` (I'm sorry, but I haven't used the math formatting before).

What is a good approximation for the hypergeometric function when `b==c` and `|b| < 100` and `b < 0` and b is an integer and `|x| < 1.0`? Thanks for your help in advance.

[image: Whole Number]
[image: Fraction]

Comment: Actually, do you have a reference for the big-F notation? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is not correct. I typed `plot 2f1(2, 1, 1, x) and (1.0 - x)^(-2) for x = 0 to 5` into wolframalpha and the results were different from `plot 2f1(2, -1, -1, x) and (1.0 - x)^(-2) for x = 0 to 5`. Something is going on here.

Comment: See e.g. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal series for ${}_2F_1([a,b],[c],x)$ is
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_k (b)_k}{k! (c)_k} x^k $$
where $(\cdot)_k$ is a Pochhammer symbol.  In the case $b = c$, the factors
$(b)_k$ and $(c)_k$ **should** cancel.  However, there is an exception when $b=c$ is a nonpositive integer: $(b)_k = 0$ when $k > -b$, so the coefficient has the indeterminate form $0/0$.  The conventional interpretation is that when
$b$ is a nonpositive integer, we ignore all terms for $k > -b$.  Thus in this case

$$ {}_2F_1([a,b],[b],x) = \sum_{k=0}^{-b} \frac{(a)_k}{k!} x^k $$

For example, your ${}_2F_1([2,-1],[-1],x) = 2x+1$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!